# Which limitiations exist in using ORACLE CUSTOM DATA TYPES as parameter in PL/SQL Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I'm involved in a pair of java project in which are used oracle stored procedures using oracle custom data type, for example ORACLE OBJECT

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ1 AS OBJECT(
      SOME_VALUE                VARCHAR2(18 CHAR)
    , SOME_OTHER_VALUE          NUMBER(3,0) 
    , ...
);
/
```

and ORACLE TABLE containg these OBJECTS

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TBL1 IS TABLE OF OBJ1;
/
```

So the Stored Procedures receive the ORACLE TABLE as parameter, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_SECURITY_CHECK AS
    
    PROCEDURE VERIFY1(
        TBL_INPUT       TBL1,
        SOME_OUTPUT     OUT NUMBER
    );
    
END PKG_CIRCUITO_DI_SICUREZZA;
```

I'm wondering if there are limitations for example in the number of columns of the ORACLE OBJECT, or in the number of ORACLE OBJECT that could be contained inside the ORACLE TABLE, when the TABLE is passed as parameter...?

I see some other question about parameter numbers or parameter size permitted, put are general question about simple data type as varchar2 or number, I did not find something specific for ORACLE CUSTOM DATA TYPES as parameter in STORED PROCEDURES.

Answer (score 2):

There are no additional *structural* limitations. Providing it's a valid Oracle type - we can create it in SQL - we can use it to define a PL/SQL parameter.

There no *numerical* limits to the number of instances of OBJ1 you can store in TBL1. However, objects are stored in session memory, so there is a ceiling, depending on how many populated attributes the object has. However, if you're stuffing so many objects into a collection you blow the MAX_PGA_TARGET that's a sign you've probably chosen the wrong approach.

Comment: I'm assuring data passed is as limited to the minimum necessary. and investigate in any possibly point of failure. I did not find anything googling about MAX_PGA_TARGET, but searching "max pga target" I came into PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT and PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET. Maybe you meant one of those?